# Grunt Serve - Works, Grunt Build/Upload - Doesn't Work (Static Site)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I am having a problem using a Grunt build that I created.

## The Problem

Everything works locally when I run `grunt serve`.  However, when I run `grunt build` and then sync the content to my S3 bucket, the `ng-view` pages are not rendered properly.  The header of the pages actually gets loaded, but the content seems to be just disappear - even plain text.

I attached the Gruntfile, bower.json and package.json currently in use.

There are no errors spit out in the development console in any browser and no 404s on the network tabs.

## Steps I Used

1. Create the template in a new directory using `yo angular`
2. Use the configuration:

   - Use Grunt, not Gulp
   - Basic AngularJS options
   - Include Sass/Compass
   - Do not include Bootstrap
3. Setup Zurb Foundation 5
4. Check `package.json` and `bower.son` dependency versions
5. Build the site using `grunt serve` to validate
6. Create an Amazon S3 bucket (`aws s3 md myTestBucket`)
7. Sync the `dist` directory in the build (`was s3 . sync s3://myTestBucket`)
8. Launch the site, the `/views` folder does not appear to be complete read

## What I Tried

- I tried hosting the files on my local Apache server **with the same results**.  However, `grunt serve` still works.
- Executed `grunt serve` on the project on a completely different machine with the source checked out - works just fine
- Dropped files on static Apache web server - did **not** work
- Removed magnification from the `/views` folder - still did **not** work

## Files

**Bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-aria": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-messages": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.9",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "foundation": "^5.5.3",
    "font-awesome-animation": "^0.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "myApp"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.3",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.2",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-jscs": "^2.6.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.12.1",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^3.1.2",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.1.0",
    "karma": "0.13.19",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.3",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile**

```
// Generated on 2016-02-04 using generator-angular 0.15.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
  });

  // add static serve
  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    appConfig: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= appConfig.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'newer:jscs:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= appConfig.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'postcss:server']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= appConfig.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= appConfig.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: false,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              serveStatic('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                serveStatic('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                serveStatic('./app/styles')
              ),
              serveStatic(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              serveStatic('.tmp'),
              serveStatic('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                serveStatic('./bower_components')
              ),
              serveStatic(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: false,
          base: '<%= appConfig.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= appConfig.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par
    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: '.jscsrc',
        verbose: true
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= appConfig.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= appConfig.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= appConfig.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    postcss: {
      options: {
        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 1 version']})
        ]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= appConfig.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
              }
            }
          }
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= appConfig.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= appConfig.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= appConfig.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= appConfig.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= appConfig.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= appConfig.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          sourcemap: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= appConfig.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= appConfig.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= appConfig.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= appConfig.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= appConfig.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>',
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>/images',
          '<%= appConfig.dist %>/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
          js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= appConfig.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= appConfig.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= appConfig.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= appConfig.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= appConfig.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= appConfig.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= appConfig.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= appConfig.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/**/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= appConfig.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    ngtemplates: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          module: 'myApp',
          htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
          usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
        },
        cwd: '<%= appConfig.app %>',
        src: 'views/{,*/}*.html',
        dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= appConfig.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= appConfig.app %>',
          dest: '<%= appConfig.dist %>',
          src: [
            '**/*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '**/*.html',
            'images/**/*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= appConfig.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= appConfig.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'postcss',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'newer:jscs',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

## !! UPDATE 2016-03-08 !!

I was able to resolve the problem by changing the tag for one of my directives!

This was causing a problem:

```
<data-generator flag="centrifuge" />
```

What fixed it was:

```
<data-generator flag="centrifuge"></data-generator>
```

I'm going to put together a tiny sample project that demonstrates it.

Comment: You haven't given us any logs or error messages from the remote server.

Comment: There actually are no errors!  I checked the logs locally and on the web server and nothing is showing up. That's what is confusing me.

Comment: My point is we can't reproduce any of this with the information you've given us.

Comment: No. Don't bundle up the project.  Trim it down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce this issue. Literally a hello world example with the minimum amount of packages needed for this. and then post the code for it (along with the necessary commands to pull down the packages); so that we can reproduce this.

Comment: I was able to find the issue but haven't solved it yet.  When everything is packed into `scripts.xxx.js` the HTML is not fully included.  I see only partial data being copied.  I'm working on trimming down the project to the minimum to make it reproducable.

Comment: I figured out where the issue was.  I'm going to put together a minimal app to reproduce it.  I'll update the issue with the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing from a full closing tag for a custom directive did the job.

I changed:

```
<data-generator flag="centrifuge" />
```

To:

```
<data-generator flag="centrifuge"></data-generator>
```